Why does the fillet tool in ArcGIS Pro delete parts of features?
I am trying to connect two lines with the fillet tool, but when I execute the tool, the two lines disappear, and only the curve remains. This is specific to one feature. The tool works fine with all other lines in the data set. I don't want to delete and digitize over again the feature in question. What is the cause of this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This seems more a Tech Support issue that a GIS SE one. It it's specific to one dataset, you'd need to provide that data, or this is likely to be unreproducible.

The Fillet Tool creates a circular arc that is tangent between two features. When you use it on two intersecting lines (for example, to create curved Right-of-Ways at intersections), the tool will force part of the line into a curve. Depending on what you're doing, you can split the line at certain areas so the tool doesn't force the entire line into a curve (again, creating curved ROW intersections). When creating ROWs, I split the line at the road line layer, then create the curve with the tool. I still have to copy parallel, split, merge, etc to keep the width a specific size.
If that doesn't work, you can just copy and paste all of the lines into a different line layer, perform the edit using the Fillet Tool, and then split, delete, merge, and cut them into the same layer. It won't have perfect tangency, but it's easier than having to redo everything.
You can also create curves using arc segments and tangent curve segments in the line editing pane.
Sometimes the tool can't create a tangent curve, so it forces all of the lines into a curve, regardless of where you split it at. It also depends on where you click on each feature.
Hope that helps.
